# Wrong number of count as result

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to get the count of tables which are not reserved for current date, for that I wrote this stored procedure but it is always giving me 0.

```
USE [RestaurantProject]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_GetAvailableTables]    Script Date: 9/17/2014 3:00:43 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetAvailableTables] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT COUNT(t.TableID) AS TableCount
    FROM Tables t
    INNER JOIN Orders o
    ON t.TableID <> o.TableID
    WHERE o.OrderDate < GETDATE()

END
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of data that are stored in both tables `Tables` and `Orders`?

Comment: There are a lot of issues here. First is the name of your procedure. sp_ is reserved for MS procedures. Really there is no reason to add a prefix to your procedure names. The next issue is you are creating a triangular join which in this case is almost a cross join. Not totally sure what you want but it seems like a left join to Orders is more appropriate. Then you add another predicate to your where clause of o.TableID IS NULL

Comment: Here is an article which explains triangular joins. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, your `join` is messed up.  I think you'd be better off using `not exists` :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Tables t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    select *
    from orders o
    where o.tableid = t.tableid and o.orderdate < getdate())
```

---

Note: this may not return the correct results.  Depends on the data in your `orders` table.  You may want to use `o.orderdate > getdate()` instead of `<`.  That would give you all the tables that don't have a reservation greater than `getdate()`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT COUNT(t.TableID) AS TableCount
FROM Tables t
left JOIN Orders o ON t.TableID = o.TableID and o.OrderDate = GETDATE()
where o.TableID is null
```

i've moved all the logic into the join clause and then filter out the records that do not match.

what we're saying is:

give me all the tables where there is no order where the order date is today.

this is going to be better performance than your query because it has a smaller result set to filter from.

if i were you i'd pass in the date that you want to check for as a parameter, this sp is going to return different results depending on when you call it which is going to make your life difficult later on if you want to reproduce the results.